# Proof for Number of Images by Inclined Mirrors

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, geometry

I learned that the formula for the number of images formed by a pair of plane mirrors is given by $$N = \frac{360^{\circ}}{\theta} - 1$$
But, when $\frac{360^{\circ}}{\theta}$ is odd and the object is placed asymmetrically, the number is given by  $$N = \frac{360^{\circ}}{\theta}$$
My question is where does this formula come from? How can it be proven?

Answer (score 0):

First you seem to assume that $360\over\theta$ is a natural number, (otherwise it makes no sense to  mention odd results. Than your formula is  right its easier to see if you add the object as the first picture, for natural numbers N as result, you  then get $N=360\over\theta$
the easiest way to show it is if you just look at the pictures of the mirrors self, maybe imaging a dot on the first mirror than the mirrored mirrors  just make the spokes in a regular polygon with N sides.